# apache mod_rewrite 500 internal error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to change

`http://localhost/inbox?pg=2` to

`http://localhost/inobox/2`

and I got a working code as below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?inbox/(\d+)$ /inbox?pg=$1 [QSD,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

however if I change 
`http://localhost/inbox/2` to

`http://localhost/inbox/2.5` or 
`http://localhost/inbox/`
I get 500 error and I am not able to figure out what is causing it. I am already checking on the php end for empty var or non numeric value however, this 500 error kicks in everytime I change it as above, does anyone know how can I redirect back to inbox.php if one of these situations happen?

log file reads
`r->uri = /inbox/2.5.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php`

`redirected from r->uri = /inbox/2.5.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `RewriteRule ^/?inbox/(\d+)$ /inbox?pg=$1 [QSD,L]` the `\d` matches only numeric characters 0-9 and not the `.`, so 2.5 does not match this rule. To match both 2 and 2.5, use `([\d.]+)` instead.

Comment: so what's the solution? is there a way to redirect back to inbox.php if those don't match?

Comment: Just updated my answer. Using a character grouping to include the `.` will achieve the match. Otherwise, the rule needs to be followed by a generic catch-all or another rule that matches 2.5.

Comment: yeah that worked, how to to handle also the `inbox/` and `inbox/2m`(mix of number and letter)?

Comment: Use `([\d.a-zA-Z]*)` This is mostly regular regex; [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) is a good tutorial for learning about character classes